# Errors while compiling project migrated to SBT - error while loading package and Assertions

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm migrating a Scala application that compiles and runs fine by manually
including jars in the classpath to a SBT build configuration.

My `build.sbt` is as follows:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.4"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "1.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-all" % "1.3"

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.scct" % "scct_2.10" % "0.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.9.2"
```

When I compile it I get the following errors:

```
Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Set current project to hello (in build file:/home/kevin/gitrepos/go-game-msc/)
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/home/kevin/gitrepos/go-game-msc/}go-game-msc...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 25 Scala sources to /home/kevin/gitrepos/go-game-msc/target/scala-2.9.2/classes...
[error] error while loading package, class file needed by package is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] error while loading Assertions, class file needed by Assertions is missing.
[error] reference value <init>$default$2 of object deprecated refers to nonexisting symbol.
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 21 s, completed 09-Mar-2014 12:07:14
```

I've tried matching up the dependencies with the jar files I am using:

```
hamcrest-all-1.3.jar   
logback-classic-1.0.13.jar  
scalaedit-assembly-0.3.7(1).jar  
scalatest_2.9.0-1.9.1.jar    
slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar  
logback-core-1.0.13.jar     
scalaedit-assembly-0.3.7.jar     
scct_2.9.2-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
junit-4.11.jar         
miglayout-4.0.jar           
scalariform.jar                  
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
```

Please advise.

Comment: Could you please move the solution (from **UPDATE**) part to an answer and approve?

Answer (score 0):

Never mix scala binary versions. 
Use always %% (instead of % and _2.x.x):

```
libraryDependencies +="org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.2"

libraryDependencies +="com.github.scct" %% "scct" % "0.2-SNAPSHOT"
```